# Pullback of Differential-Form

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Given a differential form

$$x\,dy\wedge dz-y\,dx\wedge dz+z\,dx\wedge dy$$

I am supposed to prove that the it's pullback by a linear map of determinant one leaves it invariant. For example, if $\phi$ is a linear map and $\omega$ is a differential form then $\phi^*\omega=\omega$. Also, I was wondering, can we also say that any differential 2-form that is invariant under pull back of $\phi$ is scalar multiple of $\omega$?

I know the definition that for a linear map, we have that $\phi^*\omega(V)=\omega(\phi(V))$
but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint: For any vectors $\mathbf v,\mathbf w\in\Bbb R^3$, 
$$\omega(\mathbf x)(\mathbf v,\mathbf w) = \det(\mathbf x,\mathbf v,\mathbf w).$$
Here I'm writing $\mathbf x=(x,y,z)$.

**ADDENDUM**: Here's a suggestion to address your uniqueness question. Consider two types of matrices with determinant $1$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} c^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/c \end{bmatrix} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and start with a $2$-form like $f dx\wedge dy$.

Comment: thanks for you hint. Do you have hints for the later part of my question, any 2-form that satisfies the given invariance is scalar multiple of $\omega$ defined above.

Comment: See the addendum. Have fun!

Comment: @TedShifrin: Sorry for necropost: By the notation det(x,v,w), do you mean each of x,v,w as column vectors?

Comment: @MSIS: I do, but it doesn’t matter if you use row vectors for them all.